# How do I download a PDF file using a URL link to local computer in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, url

I'm trying to download a pdf file using a URL link to my computer, but it gives the following error:

> 'Unable to connect to the remote server' SocketException: A connection
> attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
> after a period of time, or established connection failed because
> connected host has failed to respond 41.180.70.243:80

I made sure that I can open the PDF in my browser when I use the link, and it works.
(I get the link from an XML response from another server).

I am using service references to integrate to another system using SOAP.
The result that I get back from the service is a XML file:

```
TPN_Test_ConsumerService.ConsumerSoapClient consumerServiceClient = new TPN_Test_ConsumerService.ConsumerSoapClient();
var result = consumerServiceClient.ConsumerEnquiry(securityInfo, moduleList, consumerBlock, enquiryBlock);

var PdfURL = "";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(Convert.ToString(result));

XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("PdfURL");
for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
{
   PdfURL = elemList[i].InnerXml;
}

WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
byte[] pdfBytes = client.DownloadData(PdfURL);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("Path of file", pdfBytes);
```

I've tried setting the default proxy to false in the web.config file, but that also did not work.

Comment: is that url http or https scheme? The url may be protected by integration authentication, then you need to supply credentials to the webclient.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran It is a http url scheme. I've tried supplying credentials to the webclient, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: update your question to show how you pass the credentials [masking out the values]. is your code part of some server side component - if so, then the user account running that may not have access, whereas when you try from browser it works using your login.

Comment: You are not passing any credentials to the WebClient, it does not matter if you passed securityinfo to your soap client. The pdf download is a separate HTTP GET call, you need to pass credentials to webclient before calling DownloadData()

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran I've tried adding the credentials now as well, but it still gives the same error:                                                                                                             WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            byte[] pdfBytes = client.DownloadData(PdfURL);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\Development\TPN PDF\download.pdf", pdfBytes);

Comment: did you set breakpoint and really check the correctness of that url to the PDF file. the error you posted definitely seems the url is pointing to right server or missing port #

Comment: another thing worth checking, if your code runs on a server in different network, may be it is not having network/firewall access to the target website in that pdfUrl.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the PDF file and save it in Isolated Storage, to be able to view later offline.
So lets see how to do it step-by-step.

**1- Download PDF file from a link( URL ) provided by server side:**

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.OpenReadCompleted += client_OpenReadCompleted;
client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://url-to-your-pdf-file.pdf"));
```

**2- Save the downloaded PDF file in local storage:**

```
async void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length];
    await e.Result.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    using (IsolatedStorageFile storageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storageFile.OpenFile("your-file.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
}
```